# Time Machine restore on new OS

Tags: time-machine

I have a Time Machine backup of my MacBook running Lion. My install of Mountain Lion just failed, and I'm going to format the drive and install Mountain Lion anew. Will I still be able to restore my files from my Time Machine backup onto the new version of the OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Use the Migration Assistant and choose your Time Machine backup.

Comment: Thanks! I don't have a high enough score to upvote you yet, but I'll return.